# HDRP indoor scene has no diffuse indirect light

Tags: unity, lighting, hdrp

The lights in my indoor scene correctly produce direct illumination, but no indirect diffuse illumination. So the areas that aren't directly lit are completely black before exposure/post-processing. The one exception is geometry in the zone of reflection probes, which is lit somewhat. By my calculation the lights should be producing about 750 lux, which is quite bright.

I've read every part of the Unity and HDRP manuals that I can find about lighting, and a bunch of other lighting guides, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've also messed around with the lighting section of the Rendering Debugger, but I don't know how to use the information. I gather that the lightmaps aren't getting the indirect lighting baked in.

Here's an example with automatic exposure (limit min 5) and no tone-mapping. Everything visible here is static geometry. All the light sources are wide-angle spotlights. The white boxes on the ceiling also have an emissive material.
[image: example of the problem]

Notice that there's extra light around the reflection probes. (The color is coming from nearby materials.)
[image: reflection probe bounds]

And for reference, here's part of that image with default fixed exposure settings:
[image: fixed exposure]

I'm working with Unity free 2022.1.3f1 and the High-Definition Render Pipeline 13.1.8. This happens regardless of forward rendering or deferred rendering.

I've been trying to figure this out for days, so I'd greatly appreciate help.

[image: HDRP asset rendering settings]
[image: HDRP asset lighting settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the mesh did not have any normals or UV maps.